# How to convert Task to Task<Unit> with Language-Ext

Tags: c#, language-ext

Binding tasks together with https://github.com/louthy/language-ext requires tasks with return type (`Task<>`). Tasks without return type should therefore be converted into `Task<Unit>`.

Does anybody know a compact (expression only) way to convert `Task` to `Task<Unit>` in C# -- with (or without) using Language-Ext?

In other words: Is there something like `fun(...)` for `Task`?

Comment: Why do you need a (compact, expression only) way to do that using Language-Ext? Can't you do that (compact, expression only) using plain C#?

Comment: Oh, you're right. I implied that there is no compact way in plain C#. If you know any, please add it here.

I will modify the question to make this clear for everybody.

Comment: well, of course the library author has already given an exhaustive answer :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not able to test this right now, but it should do what you want.

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<Unit> ToUnit(this Task task)
    {
        await task;
        return unit;
    }
}
```

Then call:

```
task.ToUnit();
```

On your untyped tasks.  I'll probably add this to lang-ext at some point.

Comment: I have added this (under a different name) to my project. Very useful.